# library ../sqlite3.0 doesn't exist. Application crashes after loading

Tags: apportable

I am running the command "apportable load". The launch page of Apportable comes up on launch of application in device but the app crashes after that. It gives two warning messages of sqlite but not sure if the crash is linked to it.
Here's a log after I run the command:

---

```
Warning: Module GcubeV_Innovations.Bare_Acts/Bare Acts: lib /Users/gautammadaan/Documents/IPhone/Projects/Indian Acts/sqlite3.0 does not exist

Warning: Module GcubeV_Innovations.Bare_Acts/Bare Acts: lib /Users/gautammadaan/Documents/IPhone/Projects/Indian Acts/sqlite3 does not exist

[1/11] Writing Build/android-armeabi-debug/BareActs/AndroidManifest.xml
[2/11] Zipping Build/android-armeabi-debug/BareActs/BareActs-debug.apk:/assets/Info.plist
[3/11] Creating Build/android-armeabi-debug/BareActs/BareActs-resources.apk and R.java files
[4/4] Building Build/android-armeabi-debug/BareActs/BareActs-debug.apk

ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -3PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying
again after resetting USB interface

LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
usb_clear_halt() on IN endpoint: Operation timed out
usb_clear_halt() on OUT endpoint: Operation timed out
usb_clear_halt() on INTERRUPT endpoint: Operation timed out
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -3LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt

No mtp compatible devices found: Falling back to slow path
4140 KB/s (14633982 bytes in 3.451s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/BareActs-debug.apk
Success
am start -e EARLY_LIFECYCLE_DEBUG 0 -e NSUnrecognizedForwardingDisabled 1 -n GcubeV_Innovations.Bare_Acts/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=GcubeV_Innovations.Bare_Acts/com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity (has extras) }
```

---

P.S. I am using "sqlite" as parameter under "reps" in configuration.json. I've tried using sqlite_3_7_5 etc. but that just gives more errors.

Any idea why the app is crashing or the reason for warning?

Thank you

Comment: Crash is probably not related to sqlite warnings. You should investigate with debugger and/or logcat

Comment: After a lot of debugging(mostly hit and trial), realised that there were errors in configuration.json. I modified it again from scratch.  Still stuck with the below error. Working on it, if anyone of you has any idea, please share.

`File` `"/Users/gautammadaan/.apportable/SDK/lib/apportable/application/build.py", line 244, in _finalize_app_config
    new_config[key] = sorted(set(new_config[key] + config[key]))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: One option is to add some print's to the python files to get some insight.